# Page load: waterfall issue

Tags: jquery, http, nginx, html, cdn

I'm on nginx with SSL, SPDY and OCSP Stapling enabled. "Static" site. I'm trying to optimize the files loading.

Here's the waterfall:
[image]
([more details](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140928_Z6_JEB/))

You can notice I use CDNJS for jQuery and its plugins loading and Google for its web fonts.
What's causing the files not to start loading at same time? For example why there's a block of files loaded AFTER others (starting from `body-bg.jpg`)..?

I also tried to remove entirely the CDNs, hosting everything locally. Seems to be faster. But still there's the "problem" (?) of files loaded after.

[image]
([more details](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140928_63_JR8/))

Comment: The webbrowser only loads a set number of images at the same time. You should be combining (whenever possible, those png (twitter, facebook etc )into css sprites to reduce the amount of images

Comment: Oh ok, so it's only a browser limitation? Nothing to do with where they're loaded from..